# Unable to clone link using git

Tags: git, github, proxy, clone, windows-firewall

Whenever I try to clone a repo in git using the following code:
`git clone https://github.com/sudhsudhi/coursera_test.git`
I get the following error:

```
enter fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/sudhsudhi/coursera_test.git/': Failed to connect to github.com port 443: Connection refused
```

Why do I get this error and how to correct it?
 I am guessing it has something to do with firewall or proxy.I am new to using git and am not sure.
I am using a proxy server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try updating your global git config file by doing the following:

```
git config --global http.proxy http://user:password@proxy:xxxx
```

replace it with your username, password, and xxxx is the port number.

Comment: I tried this earlier ,but still am getting an error saying 'couldn't resolve proxy 'http'. I guess I am making an error in writing the proxy url. Could you please tell me how to find the proxy url.

Comment: @SudhishPuliyathamil check this answer: https://superuser.com/questions/346372/how-do-i-know-what-proxy-server-im-using

Comment: Thank you, but the problem was something else. My proxy account was disabled for some reason by my institute.I tried with my friends account it worked all fine.